# Select Id in for loop when ion-item is clicked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need help. I want to make `<ion-item>` clickable and it should contain the `id` of the device from the for-loop. Here you can see I would insert the device id in a hidden input where I would be able to select the id when  is clicked and pass it in the `(click)="openPage(itemId)` function. But this is not working.

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let data of dataDevice; (click)="openPage(i)">
  <div calss="thisS" *ngFor="let position of dataPosition">
    <ion-grid *ngIf="position.deviceId == data.id">
      <input name="itemId" [hidden]="true" ng-model="position.deviceId">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="4">
          <div class="ion-item" ng-app="" ng-init="idDev=position.deviceId">
            <div class="ion-avatar">
              <img src="./assets/icon/truck.jpg">
              <ng-template #elseBlock><button id="notification-button" class="notification-batton2">
                  <div class="ion-icon">
                    P
                  </div>
                </button></ng-template>
              <div *ngIf="position.attributes.motion; else elseBlock">
                <button id="notification-button" class="notification-batton2"
                  style="border-color:#0f8f42!important;color: #0f8f42;">
                  <div class="ion-icon" style="font-size: 9px;">
                    {{ position.speed*1.852 |number:'1.0-0'}} Km/h
                  </div>
                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
            <ion-badge color="warning custom-badge">55 min</ion-badge>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="8">
          <ion-label class="label-wrap" *ngIf="position.deviceId == data.id">
            <h2 class="tracker-header">{{data.name}}<ion-badge color="success" class="badge-key">
                <ion-icon name="key" class="icon-key"></ion-icon>
              </ion-badge>
            </h2>
            <ng-template #elseCont>
              <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon> {{position.fixTime | date:'d MMM'}}
              <ion-icon name="time-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon> {{position.attributes.hours | date:'HH:mm'}}
            </ng-template>
            <h3 *ngIf="position.attributes.motion; else elseCont">
              <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon> {{position.fixTime | date:'d MMM'}}
              <ion-icon name="time-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
              {{position.attributes.hours | date:'HH:mm'}}
              <ion-icon name="analytics" color="primary"></ion-icon>{{position.attributes.distance}}
            </h3>
            <p style="font-size: 12px;">{{position.address}} </p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you're sending index not data.itemId. You should just make

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of dataDevice; let i = index">
  <ion-item (click)="openPage(data.itemId)">
    <div class="thisS" *ngFor="let position of dataPosition">
      <ion-grid *ngIf="position.deviceId == data.id">
        <input name="itemId" [hidden]="true" ng-model="position.deviceId" />
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="4">
            <div class="ion-item" ng-app="" ng-init="idDev=position.deviceId">
              <div class="ion-avatar">
                <img src="./assets/icon/truck.jpg" />
                <ng-template #elseBlock><button
                    id="notification-button"
                    class="notification-batton2">
                    <div class="ion-icon">P</div>
                  </button></ng-template>
                <div *ngIf="position.attributes.motion; else elseBlock">
                  <button
                    id="notification-button"
                    class="notification-batton2"
                    style="border-color: #0f8f42 !important; color: #0f8f42">
                    <div class="ion-icon" style="font-size: 9px">
                      {{ position.speed*1.852 |number:'1.0-0'}} Km/h
                    </div>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <ion-badge color="warning custom-badge">55 min</ion-badge>
            </div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="8">
            <ion-label class="label-wrap" *ngIf="position.deviceId == data.id">
              <h2 class="tracker-header">
                {{data.name}}<ion-badge color="success" class="badge-key">
                  <ion-icon name="key" class="icon-key"></ion-icon>
                </ion-badge>
              </h2>
              <ng-template #elseCont>
                <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
                {{position.fixTime | date:'d MMM'}}
                <ion-icon name="time-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
                {{position.attributes.hours | date:'HH:mm'}}
              </ng-template>
              <h3 *ngIf="position.attributes.motion; else elseCont">
                <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
                {{position.fixTime | date:'d MMM'}}
                <ion-icon name="time-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
                {{position.attributes.hours | date:'HH:mm'}}
                <ion-icon name="analytics" color="primary"></ion-icon>{{position.attributes.distance}}
              </h3>
              <p style="font-size: 12px">{{position.address}}</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
  angular ionic-framework ionic4 Share
</ng-container>
```

Also you have typos in your code. please re-review your code

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I used `(click)=openPage(data.id)` with this i can call the function with the id of that clicked item

```html
<ion-item
  button
  *ngFor="let data of dataDevice; let i = index"
  (click)="openPage(data.id)"
>
  <div calss="thisS" *ngFor="let position of dataPosition">
    <ion-grid *ngIf="position.deviceId == data.id">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="4">
          <div class="ion-item" ng-app="" ng-init="idDev=position.deviceId">
            <div class="ion-avatar">
              <img src="./assets/icon/truck.jpg" />
              <ng-template #elseBlock
                ><button id="notification-button" class="notification-batton2">
                  <div class="ion-icon">P</div>
                </button></ng-template
              >
              <div *ngIf="position.attributes.motion; else elseBlock">
                <button
                  id="notification-button"
                  class="notification-batton2"
                  style="border-color: #0f8f42 !important; color: #0f8f42"
                >
                  <div class="ion-icon" style="font-size: 9px">
                    {{ position.speed*1.852 |number:'1.0-0'}} Km/h
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ion-badge color="warning custom-badge">55 min</ion-badge>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="8">
          <ion-label class="label-wrap" *ngIf="position.deviceId == data.id">
            <h2 class="tracker-header">
              {{data.name}}<ion-badge color="success" class="badge-key">
                <ion-icon name="key" class="icon-key"></ion-icon>
              </ion-badge>
            </h2>
            <ng-template #elseCont>
              <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
              {{position.fixTime | date:'d MMM'}}
              <ion-icon name="time-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
              {{position.attributes.hours | date:'HH:mm'}}
            </ng-template>
            <h3 *ngIf="position.attributes.motion; else elseCont">
              <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
              {{position.fixTime | date:'d MMM'}}
              <ion-icon name="time-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
              {{position.attributes.hours | date:'HH:mm'}}
              <ion-icon name="analytics" color="primary"></ion-icon
              >{{position.attributes.distance}}
            </h3>
            <p style="font-size: 12px">{{position.address}}</p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```